# Find the closest quarter-end for a date?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find the quarter-end closest to a given date: e.g. the closest quarter-end for 5/27/2014 would be 6/30/2014 and for 2/2/2013 would be 12/31/2012. I have the following but it doesn't give me the expected output for a date like 8/15/2015:

```
import datetime

tester = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 15)

calendar_date = datetime.datetime(tester.year - 1, 12, 31)
for dd in [(3, 31), (6, 30), (9, 30), (12, 31)]:
    diff = abs(datetime.datetime(tester.year, dd[0], dd[1]) - tester)
    if diff.days <= 45:
        calendar_date = datetime.datetime(tester.year, dd[0], dd[1])
        break

print tester, calendar_date
```

I've simplified by just assuming each quarter is 90 days and thus take 1/2 of that at 45 days (is there a better way???) but clearly that doesn't work for 8/16/2015 as it prints:

```
2015-08-15 00:00:00 2014-12-31 00:00:00
```

I was expecting 2015-09-30 00:00:00

Comment: Don't you want the min based on the absolute difference?

Comment: Do you need the full `datetime.datetime` or is `datetime.date` enough?

Comment: datetime.date would be enough....

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I need the nearest, not the min

Comment: If you have the absolute minimum you have the nearest no? Also why `2015-09-30` and not `2015-06-30 `

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your original question...the method doesn't matter I just need the nearest quarter end.

Comment: Then use the abs min as in the answer below presuming you want `2015-06-30` and not `2015-09-30 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.timedelta` might be negative and `diff.days <= 45` is always true for negative time deltas, hence the incorrect result.

You already had a simple solution with the candidates in place. These are

1. Last quarter of year before target date
2. All four quarters of the current year

`datetime.timedelta` objects have relative comparison operators, i.e. they form a total order, which means there's a minimum. As noted in the comments by Padraic Cunningham, you want the candidate with the *minimum absolute distance* to the target date:

```
def get_closest_quarter(target):
    # candidate list, nicely enough none of these 
    # are in February, so the month lengths are fixed
    candidates = [
        datetime.date(target.year - 1, 12, 31),
        datetime.date(target.year, 3, 31),
        datetime.date(target.year, 6, 30),
        datetime.date(target.year, 9, 30),
        datetime.date(target.year, 12, 31),
    ]
    # take the minimum according to the absolute distance to
    # the target date.
    return min(candidates, key=lambda d: abs(target - d))
```

The code here uses `datetime.date` for simplicity, but it should be easy to generalize to `datetime.datetime` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with comparing just two dates, using `ind = (dt.month-1) // 3 + 1` to get the index for the current quarter:

```
def find_qrt(dt):
    qrts = [date(dt.year - 1, 12, 31), date(dt.year, 3, 31),
            date(dt.year, 6, 30), date(dt.year, 9, 30),
            date(dt.year, 12, 31),
            ]
    ind = (dt.month-1) // 3 + 1
    curr_qr, last_qr = qrts[ind], qrts[ind-1]
    return curr_qr if abs(curr_qr - dt) < abs(last_qr - dt) else last_qr
```

If you want to return the later quarter in the case of a tie as per your example date we just need to use `<=`:

```
dt = datetime.date(2015, 8, 15)
from datetime import date

def find_qrt(dt):
    qrts = [date(dt.year - 1, 12, 31), date(dt.year, 3, 31),
            date(dt.year, 6, 30), date(dt.year, 9, 30),
            date(dt.year, 12, 31),
            ]
    ind = (dt.month-1) // 3 + 1
    curr_qr, last_qr = qrts[ind],qrts[ind-1]
    return curr_qr if abs(curr_qr - dt) <= abs(last_qr - dt) else last_qr

print(find_qrt(dt))
```

The first function will return `2015-06-30` because the earlier date breaks the tie, for the second we get `2015-09-30` as we take the current quarter in the event of a tie.

The first function